# How many days are in a month?

Tags: simcity-2013

Simcity graphs are all represented in months, but there doesn't seem to be ~30 days in a month. How many days are in a month?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A month is the same as a day. Therefore there are 12 days (months) in a year.

Comment: +1: For someone out of context, this answer is hilarious.

Comment: It might be hilarious but also confusing.  I'm assuming a month in game is a real day of 24 hours in actual real clock time?

Comment: These time units are not real time.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved with a separation of units in "real time" vs. "game time".  It's pretty confusing as is.

Answer (score 5):

There are 24 hours in a budget month.  You can confirm this by looking at the budget window.

```
"Profit/Loss" * 24 + "Monthly Transactions" = Monthly Profit
```

Also, you can see the current month and year by hovering over the clock in the lower left corner.